# Wordpress masonry grid not loading for large number of items

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-masonry, masonry, visual-composer

I have a Wordpress site using the Jupiter theme, using Visual Composer, hosted on a shared GoDaddy plan. I am using Visual Composer's Post Masonry Grid with lazy loading to display WooCommerce products, with 15 products loading at a time. The settings allow you to specify the max number of posts to load, or set it to `-1` for unlimited. I have noticed that if I set it to display a number greater than `125`, the masonry grid does not load at all, leaving the loading spinner spinning, and generating an error in the console:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

in `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

When I downloaded the website to run in my local XAMPP server, it loads just fine. This leads me to think that the issue is a `php.ini` configuration issue with GoDaddy, and something about loading more than 125 items is maxing something out and causing it to fail. but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: At a guess, you're exceeding the [maximum execution time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#Maximum_execution_time_exceeded) or the [memory limit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors#Allowed_memory_size_exhausted). Look at the error logs for your server, and it'll tell you what caused the problem. I know from experience that the Jupiter theme can destroy server resources if left to run wild.

Comment: @KirkBeard You nailed it! I increased those values and it fixed my problem. Thanks!